# I was trying to install pangolin but ran into an error

Tags: python, numpy, numba, pangolin

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

numba 0.57.0 requires numpy<1.25,>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.25.0 which is incompatible
```

Getting the above error I tried to use numpy 1.24.4 but when I run `cmake --build build -t pypangolin_pip_install`

It uninstalls the numpy 1.24.4 and installs the numpy 1.25